# React-router return unknown url to index.html and serve

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I refresh the page on some url like "page/sub/url/" I get an error because this is send to the server and not to the bundle in index.html. From [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server) I understand that it is possible to configure the server to just ignore such request and serve index.html. No problem here. However, in such case after refresh the user gets the default Indexroute, for example: "/" instead "page/sub/url/" where he requested the refresh initialy. Is there a way to send the "page/sub/url/" to the bundle.js and route the user to this location after he refreshed the page?

Comment: not really understanding what your exact issue is - maybe try posting your code or being more descriptive? make sure that your paths are absolute though, this is a common mistake: so `src="/bundle.js"` instead of `src="bundle.js"`

Comment: There is no specific code to show, it is generally about creating SingleAppPages. If I press F5 on some route this goes to the server instead to the client, that has the bundle with routes. I am thinking how to coordinate client and server so the users doesn't need be redirected to one default page on "F5" but stay where he is. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

OMG .. that was just super easy. Once i defined the routes on the server side and directed them to index.html the pages reloaded normaly without any errors. Begginers mistake.